# Grunt Serve seems to be stuck at Watching step

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I am creating a yo angular application and using 
`grunt serve` command to start the server. All the previous steps (http://yeoman.io/codelab/preview-inbrowser.html) seems to have worked fine to deploy the yo application and utilities required for grunt. But my {grunt serve --verbose} doesn't seem to be doing anything after certain step as mentioned in code file attached. Any suggestions?
I could find one related issue which suggests to have Gulp, but I want to solve this with Grunt: [Grunt watch tasks seem to take a very long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121361/grunt-watch-tasks-seem-to-take-a-very-long-time)

```
    Watching app/images/yeoman.png for changes.
    Execution Time (2015-10-12 02:23:30 UTC)
    loading tasks          4ms  0%
    serve                  2ms  0%
    clean:server           8ms  0%
    wiredep:app          139ms  ▇▇▇ 2%
    wiredep:test           8ms  0%
    wiredep:sass          11ms  0%
    concurrent:server     5.9s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 76%
    autoprefixer:server  430ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 6%
    connect:livereload    37ms  0%
    watch                 1.2s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 16%
    Total 7.7s

    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-44-212 client]$ grunt serve --verbose
    Initializing
    Command-line options: --verbose

    Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

    Registering Gruntfile tasks.

    Registering "grunt-autoprefixer" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/package.json...OK
    Loading "autoprefixer.js" tasks...OK
    + autoprefixer

    Registering "grunt-concurrent" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-concurrent/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-concurrent/package.json...OK
    Loading "concurrent.js" tasks...OK
    + concurrent

    Registering "grunt-contrib-clean" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean/package.json...OK
    Loading "clean.js" tasks...OK
    + clean

    Registering "grunt-contrib-compass" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/package.json...OK
    Loading "compass.js" tasks...OK
    + compass

    Registering "grunt-contrib-concat" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/package.json...OK
    Loading "concat.js" tasks...OK
    + concat

    Registering "grunt-contrib-connect" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
    Loading "connect.js" tasks...OK
    + connect

    Registering "grunt-contrib-copy" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/package.json...OK
    Loading "copy.js" tasks...OK
    + copy

    Registering "grunt-contrib-cssmin" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/package.json...OK
    Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...OK
    + cssmin

    Registering "grunt-contrib-htmlmin" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-htmlmin/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-htmlmin/package.json...OK
    Loading "htmlmin.js" tasks...OK
    + htmlmin

    Registering "grunt-contrib-imagemin" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/package.json...OK
    Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...OK
    + imagemin

    Registering "grunt-contrib-jshint" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
    Loading "jshint.js" tasks...OK
    + jshint

    Registering "grunt-contrib-uglify" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/package.json...OK
    Loading "uglify.js" tasks...OK
    + uglify

    Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
    Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
    + watch

    Registering "grunt-filerev" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-filerev/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-filerev/package.json...OK
    Loading "filerev.js" tasks...OK
    + filerev

    Registering "grunt-google-cdn" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/package.json...OK
    Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...OK
    + cdnify

    Registering "grunt-karma" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-karma/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-karma/package.json...OK
    Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...OK
    + karma

    Registering "grunt-newer" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-newer/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-newer/package.json...OK
    Loading "newer.js" tasks...OK
    + any-newer, newer, newer-clean, newer-postrun

    Registering "grunt-ng-annotate" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/package.json...OK
    Loading "ng-annotate.js" tasks...OK
    + ngAnnotate

    Registering "grunt-svgmin" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-svgmin/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-svgmin/package.json...OK
    Loading "svgmin.js" tasks...OK
    + svgmin

    Registering "grunt-usemin" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-usemin/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-usemin/package.json...OK
    Loading "usemin.js" tasks...OK
    + usemin, useminPrepare

    Registering "grunt-wiredep" local Npm module tasks.
    Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-wiredep/package.json...OK
    Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-wiredep/package.json...OK
    Loading "wiredep.js" tasks...OK
    + wiredep
    Initializing config...OK
    Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
    + build, default, serve, server, test

    Running tasks: serve

    Running "serve" task

    Running "clean:server" (clean) task
    Verifying property clean.server exists in config...OK
    Files: .tmp -> server
    Options: force=false, no-write=false
    Cleaning .tmp...
    >> 1 path cleaned.

    Running "wiredep" task

    Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
    Verifying property wiredep.app exists in config...OK
    Files: app/index.html
    Verifying property wiredep.app.src exists in config...OK
    Options: src=["app/index.html"], ignorePath={}

    Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task
    Verifying property wiredep.test exists in config...OK
    Files: test/karma.conf.js
    Verifying property wiredep.test.src exists in config...OK
    Options: devDependencies, src="test/karma.conf.js", ignorePath={}, fileTypes={"js":{"block":{},"detect":{"js":{}},"replace":{"js":"'{{filePath}}',"}}}

    Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task
    Verifying property wiredep.sass exists in config...OK
    Files: app/styles/main.scss
    Verifying property wiredep.sass.src exists in config...OK
    Options: src=["app/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}"], ignorePath={}

    Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
    Verifying property concurrent.server exists in config...OK
    Files: [no src] -> server
    Options: limit=2

        Initializing
        Command-line options: --verbose

        Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

        Registering Gruntfile tasks.

        Registering "grunt-autoprefixer" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/package.json...OK
        Loading "autoprefixer.js" tasks...OK
        + autoprefixer

        Registering "grunt-concurrent" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-concurrent/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-concurrent/package.json...OK
        Loading "concurrent.js" tasks...OK
        + concurrent

        Registering "grunt-contrib-clean" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean/package.json...OK
        Loading "clean.js" tasks...OK
        + clean

        Registering "grunt-contrib-compass" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/package.json...OK
        Loading "compass.js" tasks...OK
        + compass

        Registering "grunt-contrib-concat" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/package.json...OK
        Loading "concat.js" tasks...OK
        + concat

        Registering "grunt-contrib-connect" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
        Loading "connect.js" tasks...OK
        + connect

        Registering "grunt-contrib-copy" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/package.json...OK
        Loading "copy.js" tasks...OK
        + copy

        Registering "grunt-contrib-cssmin" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/package.json...OK
        Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...OK
        + cssmin

        Registering "grunt-contrib-htmlmin" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-htmlmin/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-htmlmin/package.json...OK
        Loading "htmlmin.js" tasks...OK
        + htmlmin

        Registering "grunt-contrib-imagemin" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/package.json...OK
        Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...OK
        + imagemin

        Registering "grunt-contrib-jshint" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
        Loading "jshint.js" tasks...OK
        + jshint

        Registering "grunt-contrib-uglify" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/package.json...OK
        Loading "uglify.js" tasks...OK
        + uglify

        Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
        Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
        + watch

        Registering "grunt-filerev" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-filerev/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-filerev/package.json...OK
        Loading "filerev.js" tasks...OK
        + filerev

        Registering "grunt-google-cdn" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/package.json...OK
        Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...OK
        + cdnify

        Registering "grunt-karma" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-karma/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-karma/package.json...OK
        Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...OK
        + karma

        Registering "grunt-newer" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-newer/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-newer/package.json...OK
        Loading "newer.js" tasks...OK
        + any-newer, newer, newer-clean, newer-postrun

        Registering "grunt-ng-annotate" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/package.json...OK
        Loading "ng-annotate.js" tasks...OK
        + ngAnnotate

        Registering "grunt-svgmin" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-svgmin/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-svgmin/package.json...OK
        Loading "svgmin.js" tasks...OK
        + svgmin

        Registering "grunt-usemin" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-usemin/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-usemin/package.json...OK
        Loading "usemin.js" tasks...OK
        + usemin, useminPrepare

        Registering "grunt-wiredep" local Npm module tasks.
        Reading /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-wiredep/package.json...OK
        Parsing /home/ec2-user/client/node_modules/grunt-wiredep/package.json...OK
        Loading "wiredep.js" tasks...OK
        + wiredep
        Initializing config...OK
        Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
        + build, default, serve, server, test

        Running tasks: compass:server

        Running "compass:server" (compass) task
        Verifying property compass.server exists in config...OK
        File: [no files]
        Options: sassDir="app/styles", cssDir=".tmp/styles", generatedImagesDir=".tmp/images/generated", imagesDir="app/images", javascriptsDir="app/scripts", fontsDir="app/styles/fonts", importPath="./bower_components", httpImagesPath="/images", httpGeneratedImagesPath="/images/generated", httpFontsPath="/styles/fonts", relativeAssets=false, assetCacheBuster=false, raw="Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n", sourcemap
        Running command: compass compile --sass-dir=app/styles --css-dir=.tmp/styles --images-dir=app/images --javascripts-dir=app/scripts --fonts-dir=app/styles/fonts --import-path=./bower_components --sourcemap --time --config /tmp/tmp-27173kj6r7hc.tmp
        directory .tmp/styles
            write .tmp/styles/main.css (2.272s)
            write .tmp/styles/main.css.map

        Done, without errors.


        Execution Time (2015-10-12 02:23:46 UTC)
        loading tasks    4ms  0%
        compass:server  2.8s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 100%
        Total 2.8s

    Running "autoprefixer:server" (autoprefixer) task
    Verifying property autoprefixer.server exists in config...OK
    Files: .tmp/styles/main.css -> .tmp/styles/main.css
    Options: browsers=["last 1 version"], cascade, diff=false, map, silent=false, remove, safe=false
    Reading .tmp/styles/main.css...OK
    Autoprefixer's process() method is deprecated and will removed in next major release. Use postcss([autoprefixer]).process() instead
    Writing .tmp/styles/main.css...OK
    File .tmp/styles/main.css created.
    Writing .tmp/styles/main.css.map...OK
    File .tmp/styles/main.css.map created (source map).

    Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
    Verifying property connect.livereload exists in config...OK
    File: [no files]
    Options: protocol="http", port=9000, hostname="localhost", base=".", directory=null, keepalive=false, debug=false, livereload=35729, open, useAvailablePort=false, onCreateServer=null, middleware=undefined
    Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000

    Running "watch" task
    Waiting...
    Verifying property watch exists in config...OK
    Verifying property watch.bower.files exists in config...OK
    Verifying property watch.js.files exists in config...OK
    Verifying property watch.jsTest.files exists in config...OK
    Verifying property watch.compass.files exists in config...OK
    Verifying property watch.gruntfile.files exists in config...OK
    Verifying property watch.livereload.files exists in config...OK
    Live reload server started on port: 35729
    Watching bower.json for changes.
    Watching .sass-cache for changes.
    Watching .tmp for changes.
    Watching app for changes.
    Watching bower_components for changes.
    Watching node_modules for changes.
    Watching test for changes.
    Watching app/scripts/app.js for changes.
    Watching app/scripts/controllers for changes.
    Watching app/scripts/controllers/about.js for changes.
    Watching app/scripts/controllers/main.js for changes.
    Watching test/spec/controllers/about.js for changes.
    Watching test/spec/controllers/main.js for changes.
    Watching app/styles/main.scss for changes.
    Watching Gruntfile.js for changes.
    Watching .sass-cache for changes.
    Watching .tmp for changes.
    Watching app for changes.
    Watching bower_components for changes.
    Watching node_modules for changes.
    Watching test for changes.
    Watching app/404.html for changes.
    Watching app/images for changes.
    Watching app/scripts for changes.
    Watching app/styles for changes.
    Watching app/views for changes.
    Watching app/index.html for changes.
    Watching app/views/about.html for changes.
    Watching app/views/main.html for changes.
    Watching .tmp/styles/main.css for changes.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: My bad. Was initially trying on remote instance. I was confused because I get Watching status on screen against the other tutorials which get a browser launch. Worked fine on my my personal machine. Should be my instance port issue.